# How to add another Word document as a section in several and have it live linked

Tags: microsoft-word

So I can't seem to find the answer, however, I have a handbook, 10 of them, and want the general sections to be managed from master Word Documents. A section on Library for example is identical in all, so I put the information in a word doc called Library, then inset it into my 10 handbooks. When I change the Library.docx file contents, I want all 10 to update with the latest content. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is the same in all versions, I'm looking now at 2010.

Go to the Insert tab, in the Text group select Object, the Object dialog box opens. Select the Create from File tab, browse for the Library.docx file, and check off the Link to File checkbox and click OK.

Do the same for all your 10 handbooks. Now you can edit the Library workbook and all 10 workbooks will get updated.

Comment: Graeme, is this a satisfied answer? If yes, please mark as accepted. Otherwise, please edit your question to describe what’s not working.

Comment: Apologies for delay. Yes that works a treat, just what I was looking for :)